# Filter Json based on selected item

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have used autocomplete function to show the option based on a Json File that can you see below. Now my goal is to filter the json file based on the item selected.

Eg: if I choose "Roma" from the autocomplete input, I need to show the value stored in the Json file about Roma:

1) Roma
2) RM
3) 2019-12-04
4) 2018-25-05

and show it in the #results DIV.

Below you can see my code.

**comuni.php**

```php
    <?php $arr = array(
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Roma",
        "provincia" => "RM",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2018-25-05"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Catania",
        "provincia" => "CT",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Milano",
        "provincia" => "MI",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Napoli",
        "provincia" => "NA",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Firenze",
        "provincia" => "FI",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Bologna",
        "provincia" => "BO",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Palermo",
        "provincia" => "PA",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Genova",
        "provincia" => "GE",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Lecce",
        "provincia" => "LE",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ),
    array(
        "nomeComune" => "Udine",
        "provincia" => "UD",
        "datasub" => "2019-12-04",
        "datapresub" => "2019-12-04"
    ));echo json_encode($arr);
```

**html**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input size="45" name="comuni" id="comuni" class="form-control large-input" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il nome del tuo Comune">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary large-input">Scopri</button>
        </span>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( function() {
        $.getJSON("comuni.php", function(data) {
            autoComplete = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                autoComplete.push(data[i].nomeComune);
            }
            $( "#comuni" ).autocomplete({
                source: autoComplete,
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 100
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/
Better you can go with typeahead.js , it's quite easy and simple to do what you want.